# Cannot get Web Element by xpath collection (Workfusion)

Tags: selenium, xpath, rpa, workfusion

In Workfusion I am iterating all elements in a HTML page that are to be found by xpath:

> //*[starts-with(@id,"FormView1_hidRevElement")][${i}]

When ${i} = 1 I get what is expected but not when ${i} > 1.

In the HTML page I have elements like:

> id="FormView1_hidRevElement12636"
>
> id="FormView1_hidRevElement12637"
>
> id="FormView1_hidRevElement12642"

etc,

Error thrown:
...

```
  Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //*[starts-with(@id,"FormView1_hidRevElement")][2]
```

...

What is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The XPath which you have created is wrong because

> //*[starts-with(@id,"FormView1_hidRevElement")]

will return the matching count as 3 for the below id's

> id="FormView1_hidRevElement12636"
>
> id="FormView1_hidRevElement12637"
>
> id="FormView1_hidRevElement12642"

And the each id match equals to 1 then obviously >1 condition will throw an error because it doesn't exist.

Try this XPath:

> (//*[starts-with(@id,"FormView1_hidRevElement")])[${i}]

Comment: @Feliks click that check mark near the answer to further appreciate Ali's help ;) (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)